# Errors after reconstructing odoo.conf file odoo 10 enterprise

Tags: odoo, config

Our odoo.conf file was maliciously deleted. 
after reconstructing we are able to login to odoo but there are still erors

example error (in dutch):

Fout context:
Weergave`sale.order.form`
[view_id: 516, xml_id: sale.view_order_form, model: sale.order, parent_id: n/b]

I think the errors originate from a faulty reconstructed odoo.conf, I will also add it here:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = supersecretpassword!
addons_path =/opt/odoo/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/enterprise
```

We are able to login to odoo web interface but as soon as we want to see a page we get an error like the above(different views/fields)

Comment: can you post the errors that you are getting?

Comment: Please provide more details: what error, which config...